# Does writing a newline character into a sysctl (/proc/sys) file have any effect?

Tags: linux, kernel, sysctl

Today I ran into some code that's writing a newline character explicitly into a sysctl file.  See moby/docker [source code](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a461373146d11606cecb5e9ec142a71182fc9813/libnetwork/drivers/bridge/setup_ipv6.go#L105).  My first thought is that the author has diligently copied the shell's behaviour into go despite the newline being redundant.

But then I started to look for documentation on the subject and found it a really hard one to find information on either way. I haven't managed to come up with anything so far.

---

When writing sysctl files in `/proc/sys/` many of the values are integers written in ASCII.  For example, to toggle something on or off you have to write `1` or `0` as text into a file.

Often the advice here on U&L and on blogs etc. is to do this in the shell using `echo`.  For example turning on IPv4 forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

**But** this advice does something subtly different to its stated goal.   It doesn't write a single byte 0x31 to the file.  It writes two: 0x31 0x0A also known as `1\n`.  I had always assumed the newline (0x0A) was simply ignored by the kernel.

---

Does writing a newline character into a sysctl file (eg `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`) have any effect?  *References welcome even if they are links to source code.*

Comment: Some files do complain when you try to write a newline, but some don't. Let me see if I can find an example of the complainers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases it shouldn’t make any difference either way, at least at the end of an input string. In all cases, only written data is processed — the kernel knows how long the supplied buffer is (1 byte for `1` with no newline, 2 for `1` with a newline) and will only process that many bytes.

`sysctl` entries using [the standard `sysctl`-handling functions](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.1/source/kernel/sysctl.c) handle newlines explicitly: [in strings, they terminate input](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.1/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L247), [in vectors, they separate entries](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.1/source/kernel/sysctl.c#L555) (most numeric values end up being handled as vectors, *e.g.* [`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.17.1/source/net/ipv4/devinet.c#L2424)). This is in addition to reaching the end of user input, which always ends processing.

So the following all produce the same result:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ printf 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ printf '1\n0\n' > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Thus the answer to

> Does writing a newline character into a sysctl (/proc/sys) file have any effect?

is yes: it indicates the end of a value. That indication may or may not add information compared to the end of the input as a whole; that depends on the context (specifically, whether the value being written is a vector or not).

Code handling *output* for `sysctl`, *i.e.* producing the text that’s read when something reads from a `sysctl` entry, always adds a terminating newline, as might be expected.

The `sysctl` utility [always writes a newline](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/4f55ee227d6ff3d077ce151bbf90cb29d1c92452/sysctl.c#L589), so it’s safe to assume that in most cases this will continue to be valid.

(I haven’t checked *all* the `sysctl` handlers so there may be some specific handlers which object to newlines.)